# How can I use a query of id's for another query with eloquent - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to back-end development and I am trying to use an intermediary table inside my controller to select the campaigns from user 5. So far I get the following error with the following code. I don't really understand what the error means and the google results are not really helping.

> "stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

```
public function index()
{
    $userCampaignIDs = CampaignUser::where('user_id', '5');
    $campaigns = Campaign::findMany('id', $userCampaignIDs);
    return $campaigns;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$userCampaignIDs` is not an array, but a QueryBuilder.

You have to get an array to use `findMany`, like this :

```
$userCampaignIDs = CampaignUser::where('user_id', '5')->get()->pluck('id');
```

But, you have to use Eloquent relations to get your relations more easily, like :

```
$userId = 5;
$campaigns = Campaign::whereHas('campaignUser', function($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

I suppose there is a relation between `Campaign` and `CampaignUser`